# Using a USB to HDMI adapter on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, drivers, usb, hdmi

I just bought a USB to HDMI adaptor branded by wopow. When I use it to connect a computer to an external monitor, instead of sending the signal to the monitor, Ubuntu shows a new external drive. In this drive there is a single file, named `FL2000-2.1.34054.0.exe`. I gather it would install drivers on Windows.

How can get it to work on Ubuntu? Do I need drivers of some sort?

**Update I**: the outputs [request by mikewhatever](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1040358/using-a-usb-to-hdmi-adapter-on-ubuntu-16-04?noredirect=1#comment1694465_1040358):

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 1d5c:2000  
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04ca:7053 Lite-On Technology Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 138a:003f Validity Sensors, Inc. VFS495 Fingerprint Reader
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 027: ID 0d8c:013c C-Media Electronics, Inc. CM108 Audio Controller
Bus 001 Device 026: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 025: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 024: ID 046d:c077 Logitech, Inc. M105 Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 023: ID 058f:6387 Alcor Micro Corp. Flash Drive
Bus 001 Device 020: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

$ dmesg | tail
[35257.770998] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] 2047 4096-byte logical blocks: (8.38 MB/8.00 MiB)
[35257.771267] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
[35257.771268] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 03 00 00 00
[35257.771385] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page found
[35257.771389] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[35257.774298]  sdc:
[35257.774957] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI disk
[35288.908270] usb 2-2: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[35289.274203] FAT-fs (sdc): Volume was not properly unmounted. Some data may be corrupt. Please run fsck.
[37422.954276] perf: interrupt took too long (4994 > 4977), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 40000
```

**Update II**: the output of `dmesg` after connecting the adapter and then waiting for it to be mounted as an external drive:

```
$ dmesg | tail -n 50
[ 1433.136106] usb 1-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 1433.136108] usb 1-1.3: Product: USB Receiver
[ 1433.136110] usb 1-1.3: Manufacturer: Logitech
[ 1433.218577] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[ 1433.218579] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[ 1433.223819] input: Logitech USB Optical Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2:1.0/0003:046D:C077.0001/input/input30
[ 1433.237368] logitech-djreceiver 0003:046D:C52B.0004: hiddev0,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Device [Logitech USB Receiver] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1.3/input2
[ 1433.281640] hid-generic 0003:046D:C077.0001: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [Logitech USB Optical Mouse] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1.2/input0
[ 1433.371522] input: Logitech K360 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.2/0003:046D:C52B.0004/0003:046D:4004.0005/input/input31
[ 1433.371860] logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:4004.0005: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Logitech K360] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1.3:1
[ 1433.711345] scsi 2:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Generic  Flash Disk       8.07 PQ: 0 ANSI: 4
[ 1433.712056] sd 2:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[ 1433.712820] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] 3952640 512-byte logical blocks: (2.02 GB/1.88 GiB)
[ 1433.714273] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[ 1433.714277] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 23 00 00 00
[ 1433.715833] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[ 1433.726919]  sdb: sdb1
[ 1433.729388] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[ 1449.875350] logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:4004.0005: HID++ 2.0 device connected.
[ 1457.802263] FAT-fs (sdb1): Volume was not properly unmounted. Some data may be corrupt. Please run fsck.
[ 1489.800631] usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 11 using xhci_hcd
[ 1489.940788] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=1a40, idProduct=0101
[ 1489.940800] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
[ 1489.940809] usb 1-2: Product: USB 2.0 Hub
[ 1489.942228] hub 1-2:1.0: USB hub found
[ 1489.942302] hub 1-2:1.0: 4 ports detected
[ 1490.060435] usb 2-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[ 1490.080921] usb 2-2: New USB device found, idVendor=1d5c, idProduct=2000
[ 1490.080931] usb 2-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[ 1490.083133] usb-storage 2-2:1.3: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 1490.083952] scsi host4: usb-storage 2-2:1.3
[ 1490.248318] usb 1-2.2: new full-speed USB device number 12 using xhci_hcd
[ 1490.372098] usb 1-2.2: New USB device found, idVendor=0d8c, idProduct=013c
[ 1490.372110] usb 1-2.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 1490.372118] usb 1-2.2: Product: USB PnP Sound Device
[ 1490.372127] usb 1-2.2: Manufacturer: C-Media Electronics Inc.      
[ 1490.377185] input: C-Media Electronics Inc.       USB PnP Sound Device as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2.2/1-2.2:1.3/0003:0D8C:013C.0006/input/input32
[ 1490.437452] hid-generic 0003:0D8C:013C.0006: input,hidraw3: USB HID v1.00 Device [C-Media Electronics Inc.       USB PnP Sound Device] on usb-0000:00:14.0-2.2/input3
[ 1490.511974] usbcore: registered new interface driver snd-usb-audio
[ 1491.085620] scsi 4:0:0:0: Direct-Access                               A001 PQ: 0 ANSI: 4
[ 1491.086929] sd 4:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[ 1491.087020] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] 2047 4096-byte logical blocks: (8.38 MB/8.00 MiB)
[ 1491.087199] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
[ 1491.087209] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 03 00 00 00
[ 1491.087395] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page found
[ 1491.087414] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 1491.091934]  sdc:
[ 1491.094229] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI disk
[ 1522.768849] usb 2-2: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[ 1523.131024] FAT-fs (sdc): Volume was not properly unmounted. Some data may be corrupt. Please run fsck.
```

Comment: Outputs of `lsusb` and `dmesg | tail` could be beneficial. As is, the question has zero technical info about the device.

Comment: Run `dmesg | tail` directly after you have connected the  "USB to HDMI adapter".

Comment: Looks like you need to use `usbmodeswitch` to switch the USB controller on the device from storage to display adapter mode. The same situation often occurs and the procedure is the same for USB modems and there are a few Q&As about those on AU. Unfortunately I now next to nothing else about the topic.

Comment: @DavidFoerster I am yet to find how `usb_modeswitch` can switch to display mode. Any details would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

The chip in the USB 3.0 to HDMI adapter is a Fresco Logic FL2000.

There is a drivers for Linux from the chip manufacturer.

https://github.com/FrescoLogic/FL2000

The driver is for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, kernel version 3.10.x. If compiled for a newer kernel it will have to be adapted to changed API's to work.

Comment: By this time I have been able to compile the driver, load it with `insmod` and send a test image to an external monitor with the `fltest` tool. Now what? Ubuntu still reports only one display. Please expand your answer with instructions on how to use this driver.

Comment: Did you try a new question?